# Passenger and Nginx wont start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I've got a brand new Ubuntu 13.04 server with fresh installs and updates of RVM, ruby 1.9.2 and my app.  I did a gem install passenger and that ran fine.  When I try to start passenger via

```
passenger start
```

I get

```
*** ERROR ***
Could not start Passenger Nginx core:
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open()
"/tmp/passenger-standalone.14080/logs/error.log" failed (2: No such file or directory)
2013/05/26 15:11:51 [emerg] 14091#0: could not build the types_hash, you should
increase either types_hash_max_size: 1024 or types_hash_bucket_size: 32
Stopping web server... done
```

My nginx binary appears to be in

```
/home/gary/.passenger/standalone/4.0.3/nginx-1.4.1-x86_64-linux-gcc4.7.3-1002/nginx
```

and is precompiled with the prefix flag set to /tmp   I do not appear to have an nginx.conf file anywhere on the system.   I put one in /etc/nginx and one in /tmp/nginx that only has the directive

```
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
```

but trying to restart I get the same error and I belive the conf file is ignored.   There seems to be no easy way to configure nginx if installed via passenger.  Is there an easy way to do this or should I just switch back to mongrel?

Comment: This smells like permission issues. Try running it as root to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem has been [fixed in Phusion Passenger](https://github.com/FooBarWidget/passenger/pull/80) 2 days ago. You can apply the patch yourself, or wait for version 4.0.4.